# array of functions c++ Error initialising?

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to create an array of boolean functions, this is currently where I am at.

```
typedef bool(*fn)(DIYObject*, DIYObject*);


static fn collisionfunctionArray[] =
{   
    DIY::sphere2Sphere
};


bool DIY::sphere2Sphere(DIYObject* obj1, DIYObject* obj2)
{

    DIYSphere *sphere1 = dynamic_cast<DIYSphere*>(obj1);
    DIYSphere *sphere2 = dynamic_cast<DIYSphere*>(obj2);

    if (sphere1 != NULL && sphere2 != NULL)
    {
        float X;
        X= sphere1->m_position.x - sphere2->m_position.x;
        X = X *X; 

        float Y;
        Y = sphere1->m_position.y - sphere2->m_position.y;
        Y = Y *Y;

        float distance;
        distance = sqrt(X + Y);

        float distanceCompare;
        distanceCompare = sphere1->m_radius + sphere2->m_radius;

        if (distance < distanceCompare)
        {
            sphere1->m_velocity = vec3(0,0,0);
            sphere2->m_velocity = vec3(0, 0, 0);
        }

    }
    return false;
}
```

So at the moment I am only trying to insert one function into the array but I am receiving the following error

> > `Error    2   error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'bool (__thiscall DIY::* )(DIYObject *,DIYObject *)' to 'fn'`

I think I'm taking in the same arguments so I don't really understand what the issue is here. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `sphere2Sphere` is a member function of the `DIY` class and needs an object to put in its `this` pointer.

As your `sphere2Sphere` function doesn't use the `this` pointer (I think), you can make it `static`, which means it will then match the `fn` type (as the compiler will know it doesn't need the (hidden) `this` parameter).

Note: The `static` keyword goes in the method declaration in your class definition, which you haven't shown here.

Comment: Thank you, you are a genius, if only my teacher set his tutorials with such clarity